# How do I escape a parenthesis and single quotes in botium

Tags: regex

My botium card is as follows:

```
PGI

#me
What is PGI

#bot
The total amount of dollars from a transaction \(what the client pays\).
```

My test returns:

```
ASSERTION FAILED in TextMatchAsserter - Expected: "The total amount of dollars from a transaction /(what the client pays at closing/)/."  - Actual: "The total amount of dollars from a transaction (what the client pays at closing)."
```

I have tried the following:

```
The total amount of dollars from a transaction /(what the client pays/).
The total amount of dollars from a transaction \(what the client pays\).
The total amount of dollars from a transaction /(what the client pays/)/.
The total amount of dollars from a transaction \(what the client pays\)\.
```

Is there a a website for regex information, everywhere I search for regex information I get back information on coding an assertion to match an escape sequence instead of how to USE an escape sequence

Also the following botium card is failing, not sure why:

```
Glossaries Company Profit

#me 
what is company profit

#bot
The portion of the agent's split that is paid to the company until the agent reaches their yearly cap. The center uses the company profit to pay its bills.
```

I have tried doing a agent/'s, agent\'s, / in front of all the periods, \ in front of all the periods, and / or \ only in front of the middle periods.

Comment: what if you just dont escape anything ? what matching mode are you using ?

Answer (score 1):

In a .net regex I use the hexadecimal escape codes of `\x22` (") and `\x27` (') for the escapes. You may need to use `\\x22` depending on the application.

Answer (score 0):

In Botium, the default matching mode is "wildcardIgnoreCase" - which is basically an easy form of regular expressions (* matches everything) (see [Botium Wiki](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/360603/Botium+Configuration+-+Capabilities#SCRIPTING_MATCHING_MODE)).

There is no need to escape anything, this should work:

```
PGI

#me
What is PGI

#bot
The total amount of dollars from a transaction (what the client pays).
```

You can test it in [this repl](https://repl.it/@FlorianTreml/replit-botium-bindings-julie-1).